# getting connection failure in coldfusion 9 even after installing the certificate

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, ssl-certificate, coldfusion-9, cfhttp

When I typed to verify the cert:

```
C:\Coldfusion9\runtime\jre\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts -alias myexportedcert
 -storepass changeit
```

I got the folowing displayed on my command prompt:

```
Alias Name:myexportedxert
Creation Date: Aug 22,2014
Entry type: trustedCertentry
Owner: some details here
Extensions: some details here
```

Before verifying, I added the cert by typing the following path:

```
C:\Coldfusion9\runtime\jre\bin>keytool -import -v -alias exported -file C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\lib\security\myexportedcert.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469194/coldfusion-https-connection-failure/20475763#20475763) by Miguel-F and I got the **certificate was added to keystore [Storing Cacerts]** message. I then restarted the ColdFusion 9 application server, but I am still getting a connection failure message.

**Another Information:**

The "Java Virtual Machine Path" in my ColdFusion administrator is pointing to:

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre
```

Should it  be pointing to `C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre` ?

Comment: A common mistake is importing the cert into the wrong keystore, [as mentioned in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469194/coldfusion-https-connection-failure/20475763#comment30639595_20475763). Sounds like that  is what is happening. You need to import it into the jvm that your CF server is actually using. In your case, ie `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_38`.

Comment: Thanks Leigh. Infact that was the problem.

Comment: It is a mistake most of us make at least once ;-) Glad you got it working. Since the other thread already answers this question, I am going vote to mark this thread as a duplicate.