# <cfhttp> to download a remote .csv file in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfhttp, coldfusion-2016, cfhttpparam

I'm trying to download a .csv file on a remote server location using ColdFusion (version 2016). I used the cfhttp tag to perform this operation but I keep getting the following error:

```
401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

I checked with the server admin of the remote server to verify that I have the right domain name, userid and password and the admin confirmed it. I couldn't find anything similar on SO, hence posting this question. Hoping someone can help me out.

PS: I don't have access to the ColdFusion Administrator since it is hosted by a separate team.

Below is my code (actual values replaced with dummy data for security):

```
  <cfhttp  url="https://xxx.yyy.com/abcd/xyz/myfolder/myFile.csv">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization"  
        value="Basic #ToBase64("MydomainName\Myuserid:Mypassword")#" />
  </cfhttp>
  <cfdump  var="#cfhttp.filecontent#" label="CSV file content">
  <cfabort>
```

Comment: The web server that hosts the .csv file needs to be configured to serve .csv files. Are you confident that it is?

Comment: Redtopia - yes, I'm able to open the csv file if I type in the url in a browser, which means that the server is configured to serve csv files.

Comment: Is it the https connection? And is the auth header in the correct format?  EDIT: 401 means you aren't properly logged in.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469194/coldfusion-https-connection-failure

Comment: @Shawn - I'm able to successfully connect to a different remote location with the same csv file using https; it's just this remote server I'm having a problem with.

Comment: If you're certain it uses "Basic Authentication", [cfhttp](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html) supports that. Rather than trying to generate the "Authorization" header manually, have you tried using the `username` and `password` attributes instead? *".. Use to pass a user name to the target URL for Basic Authentication. Combined with password to form a base64 encoded string that is passed in the Authenticate header. "*

Comment: @Ageax - tried that approach as well (separate username & password params) - still get the same '401 UNAUTHORIZED' error.

Comment: Did you verify the other end is using "Basic Authentication" (default)? If they're using NTLM, try specifying `authType="NTML"`  (may also need to specify the `domain`). https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your auth string is wrong. To avoid confusion and while debugging, I would suggest something like this:

---

```
<cfset myDomainName = "MydomainName" />
<cfset myUserId = "Myuserid" />
<cfset myPassword = "Mypassword" />

<cfset authString = "Basic " & ToBase64('#myDomainName#' & '\' & '#myUserId#' & ':' & '#myPassword#') />

<cfhttp  url="https://xxx.yyy.com/abcd/xyz/myfolder/myFile.csv">

  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization"  
        value="#authString#" />

</cfhttp>

<cfdump  var="#cfhttp.filecontent#" label="CSV file content">
<cfabort>
```

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: I used a different url (that is working) by mistake and it read the file. Getting the same 401 Unauthorized error with the right url.

Comment: @RogerDodger Is that URL on a different domain or not HTTPS?

Comment: @Shawn - it is https because when I type the full url in a browser, I'm able to access the csv file without any problem; the domain name is different from the url - that shouldn't be an issue, correct?

Comment: You can access `https://xxx.yyy.com/abcd/xyz/myfolder/myFile.csv` from a browser? How about from a browser on the ColdFusion server? It sounds like you may need to import the certificate into CF.

Comment: I don't have access to the CF server as it is hosted externally; importing the cert is not an option for me. I'm now switching over to cfsharepoint to see if I have any luck with that.