# cfhttp returning a connection failure for a network url that a browser can reach via both http and https

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, coldfusion-2018

I am using cfhttp to try to pull some json from one of our organizations APIs.  I have the code working when trying to pull example json from one of our own servers, but when I point it to the API itself I receive a connection failure.  This is the code:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://[url]/api/menu">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL"     name="id"   value="[guid]">
</cfhttp>
<cfset FileWrite("#application.tempDirPath#/temp.json", CFHTTP.FileContent)>
```

I have replaced the real values with [url] and [guid].

I have tried accessing this url in a browser at https://[url]/api/menu?id=[guid] and it works perfectly fine, indicating that my machine has no problem reaching that url.  The url is a server in our network that I can access as long as I'm on the company VPN.

Things that I have tried:

- The live code should point to https.  I've tried both http and https.
- I've tried hitting the home page at that same url and it also results in a connection failure, but works in a browser.
- I've tried this same code with http://www.google.com, and that downloads the Google html without issue.
- I've tried restarting ColdFusion and my machine.
- I've tried disabling compression via headers:

  ```
  <cfhttp method="get" url="http://[url]/api/menu">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0" />
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0" />
      <cfhttpparam type="URL"           name="id"          value="[guid]">
  </cfhttp>
  ```

I do not have access to the target server.  I can ask those who do have access for help, but their conclusion at this point is "this is a ColdFusion problem.", so I'm not sure how much help I can get.  This makes it impossible for me to check for Firewall rules or user-agent restrictions; suggestions on ways to test for those things locally would be welcome.

**Edit**

Per comments on this question I determined that http is just redirecting to https at that address.  So I followed the instructions provided at [ColdFusion https connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469194/coldfusion-https-connection-failure) to import the certificate.  After doing so I followed the instructions to verify that the cert was imported successfully.  I then restarted CF Server.

After that I ran my code again and dumped the cfhttp struct as a whole into the temp file.  This was the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STRUCT ID="1">
   <ENTRY NAME="Errordetail" TYPE="STRING">I/O Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target</ENTRY>
   <ENTRY NAME="Mimetype" TYPE="STRING">Unable to determine MIME type of file.</ENTRY>
   <ENTRY NAME="Statuscode" TYPE="STRING">Connection Failure.  Status code unavailable.</ENTRY>
   <ENTRY NAME="Filecontent" TYPE="STRING">Connection Failure</ENTRY>
   <ENTRY NAME="Responseheader" TYPE="STRUCT">
      <STRUCT ID="2" />
   </ENTRY>
   <ENTRY NAME="Text" TYPE="BOOLEAN">true</ENTRY>
   <ENTRY NAME="Charset" TYPE="STRING" />
   <ENTRY NAME="Header" TYPE="STRING" />
</STRUCT>
```

Comment: You CFHTTP is calling HTTP but your browser is hitting HTTPS. Does the server accept connections on port 80 and 443?

Comment: Could also do with a more specific error message

Comment: Sounds like a certificate issue. Does `http://[url]/` redirect to `https://[url]/`? `cfhttp` follows redirects by default, possibly hitting the certificate. Try using `<cfhttp redirect="false" method=...` to see if the connection is even established on the default HTTP port.

Comment: @haxtbh I've tried both http and https on my browser and my cfhttp.  Both work in browser and both fail in cfhttp.  I have tried specifying port 443 as well.  "Connection Failure" is the only message that appears in cfhttp's filecontent.

Comment: @Alex You may be right.  Writing out the full cfhttp struct I see "I/O Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".  I went back to the browser and there is a redirect I didn't notice before.  I'll read up on importing a certificate.  I saw it didn't work on http and just jumped to the conclusion it wasn't an https issue.