cfhttp returning Connection Failure from my site, but working from testing in trycf.com
I am trying to test a very simple cfhttp request on my server.
<cfhttp 
    result="result"
    method="GET"
    charset="utf-8"
    url="https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/"
>
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#result#">

When I execute this I get the following response:
struct
Charset [empty string]
ErrorDetail I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Filecontent Connection Failure
Header  [empty string]
Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader  
struct [empty]
Statuscode  Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
Text    YES

(image attached which is a little clearer)

It works when running from here: https://trycf.com/ (I am trying to register and/or reset my password as I am sure I have used this service in the past) but here is a screendump showing the result

The default setup for trycf.com seems to be Lucee 5 (I think my server is running ColdFusion9) but I also tried setting it to ColdFusion10 in the dropdown.
Is it possible the trycf.com site is using a proxy, and/or setting headers or other params (although this would seem like a stupid thing to do as it doesn't replicate what the code should be doing, show correct error handling).
Any help much appreciated.
EDIT 1
Ah there is a saved gist working here: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=5c1f9845-6826-4c6d-bda8-1c31fc77bcfd/6e8d8081-64af-424e-ac49-aace01ccb159/d580334a-6835-4672-8e0a-b2fb36910ebc.cfm
But you have to select an older ColdFusion version in the dropdown at the bottom.

Ok this thread seems to have a few pointers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469194/coldfusion-https-connection-failure I am on http and trying to access https (although I would have thought it would be OK that way around). It's not my server so I can't change any of the settings, but I will work through that thread and see if I can make progress.

YES! finally got in touch with the Admin, he knew about a limitation with CF9, so as a workaround I can use this code:
<cfx_http5
    out="response"
    method="get"
    url="https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/"
    ssl="5"
    timeout="10000"
>

<cfoutput>#response#</cfoutput>

It works like a charm.
